# How to append vectors by creating multiple vectors in a loop

Tags: r

I have a loop to create multiple vector and for each vector, I will append a data from a dataset. Here is my sample code

```
for (i in 1:10) {
assign(paste('v',i, sep = "", collapse = NULL),vector())
assign(paste('v',i, sep = "", collapse = NULL),vector()) <- append(assign(paste('v',i, sep = "", collapse = NULL),vector()),json_file$rows[i] )
}
```

However, it returned error " target of assignment expands to non-language object"
Please advise how to fix it. Thank you !

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data frame with dput()? And also the desired output of what you want. It is not much clear from your question.

Comment: I think the data frame is not the key here. My desire is to append a vector to an empty vector so if you just change json_file$rows[i] to c(1,2,3), it will still show the same error. Since the empty vector is created by variable i so I'd like to know how it can append a vector, hopefully it clarifies. Thanks

Comment: Still not very clear... The best way to help us help you is to follow the advice you were given: post sample data using `dput()` and also an example of your desired results.